# How to copy a file name in a directory to a flat file using shell script

Tags: shell

I have a directory that contains a file called oracle.txt. I need to copy the file name to a flat file I tried using the CP command but it tells me that I am copying a directory. I tried the cat command but that copies the contents not the name. Is there a command to copy Oracle.txt (the name not the contents) to a flat file? So after it completes there will be a file called process.txt and its contents will be oracle.txt

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. To debug this, we need to know which commands you actually ran, what they did, and what you expected them to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the names of the files in directory using the `ls` command.
Then you have to redirect that output to a file using `>` 
The command required is shown below.

```
ls > process.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`cp file1 file2` will copy the *contents* of `file1` over `file2`. `cat file1 > file2` does the same thing. `echo file1 > file2` will replace the contents of `file2` with the *string* `file1` (followed by a newline).

The [Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/) has much more.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the file names and their location on your machine then you can use following command, `ls /path/to/your/file > flat_file_name` This command will list all the files from your expected directory and will put those names in your flat file.

The sign '>' will overwrite all contents from flat file. If you want to append in the file use '>>' instead of '>'.

Comment: I have to do the same thing for a SQL server using Powershell how would you do the same thing using Powershell?  I tried using Copy-Item but that copies the entire contents I just need the name of the file like you did with the ls command